# Pass reactive props to lazy loaded React components mapped with object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, jsx

I have a few lazy loaded components which the user loads on demand by the click of a button, the problem is the way I pass them their props as I cannot seem to figure out another way as each components takes different props and I could pass all the availabe props to whichever component is loaded, but that would be inconvient. The code below shows how I load and render each component and how their props are passed to them:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, lazy, useRef } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { CircularLoader } from '../Common/Loaders';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';


const ChangePassword = lazy(() => import('./Security/ChangePassword'));
const UsernameLoginSwitch = lazy(() => import('./Security/UsernameLoginSwitch'));

const mapLazyComponents = {
  ChangePassword: ChangePassword,
  UsernameLoginSwitch: UsernameLoginSwitch,
}

function AccountSecurity(props) {

  const { currentUser, isAuthenticated, reloadUser } = {...props};
  const [currentComponentName, setCurrentComponentName] = useState(null);
  const Component = mapLazyComponents[currentComponentName];
  const [currentComponentProps, setCurrentComponentProps] = useState(Object());
  const currentUserRef = useRef(currentUser.user);

  useEffect(() => {
      currentUserRef.current = currentUser.user;
  });

  const settingsComponents = [
   {
      id: 1,
      name: 'ChangePassword',
      description: 'Change Password',
      Component: 'ChangePassword',
      props: {
        currentUser: currentUserRef.current,
        isAuthenticated,
        reloadUser
      }
    },
   {
      id: 2,
      name: 'UsernameLoginSwitch',
      description: 'Set Username Login Option',
      Component: 'UsernameLoginSwitch',
      props: {
        enableUsernameLogin: currentUserRef.current.can_login_with_username,
        reloadUser: reloadUser,
        currentUser: currentUserRef.current,
      }
    },
  ]

  const loadComponent = name => {
    const module = settingsComponents.find( module => module.name === name );
    if(module) {
      setCurrentComponentProps(module.props);
      setCurrentComponentName(name);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Paper>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography 
            variant="h5" 
            gutterBottom>
            Account Settings and Security
          </Typography>
          {currentUser.isLoading &&
            <CircularLoader />
          }
          {currentUser.isLoaded &&
            <React.Fragment>
              {settingsComponents.map((setting) => (
                <Button 
                  key={setting.id}
                  color="primary" 
                  variant="text"
                  onClick={() => loadComponent(setting.name)}>
                    {setting.description}
                </Button>
              ))}
              {currentComponentName &&
                <React.Suspense fallback={<CircularLoader />}>
                  <Divider />
                  <Component {...currentComponentProps}/>
                </React.Suspense>
              }
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
}

AccountSecurity.propTypes = {
  currentUser: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  reloadUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default AccountSecurity;
```

As you see above, I use the function loadComponent to set the current component and its props that are are available in settingsComponents, the problem here is that when each of this components is rendered, they are passed the props only once and never update when any of the props update (e.g. currentUser) unlike the usual way of directly passing props as in:

```
<Component currentUser={currentUser} />
```

This is expected as settingsComponents is just a simple array which is not reactive. So my question is: how do I pass the current component its respective props that are reactive (update when they change), I really been having some hard time trying many methods including the one above using the useRef in hope it catches any changes with the help of useEffect which renders whenever currentUser prop changes. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be swapping between too many different components, or even if you are, conditional rendering of them may be the way to go.

```js
function AccountSecurity(props) {

    ...
 
    const LazyComponent = () => {
        if(module.name === 'ChangePassword'){
             return <ChangePassword 
                 currentUser={currentUserRef.current}
                 unauthenticated={isAuthenticated}
                 reloadUser={reloadUser}
             />
        } else if(...){
            ...
        }
    }
    return (
        ...
        {currentComponentName &&
                    <React.Suspense fallback={<CircularLoader />}>
                      <Divider />
                      <LazyComponent/>
                    </React.Suspense>
                  }
        ...
    )
}
```

On a state change, LazyComponent will handle switching the Component or updating the component's props. Saves you from storing a snapshot of the props in the settingsComponent array.

Comment: Dylan, before switching to object key mapped components loading and rendering, I had exactly a similar approach as yours, but it has a lot of boilerplate, which is why I gone with the aformentioned approach and had it perfectly working for n components that do not take any props, but it's an issue with the ones that do take props - and different ones.